# Cannot clone github repository - Logon failed

Tags: github

I'm trying to clone a github repository locally using the following command

git clone https://github.com/*myuser*/*myrepo.git*

This brings up the authentication dialog

[image]

Here I am using the exact same credentials with which I can login to the website.

But I always get a Logon failed error.

I am not using two factor authentication and tried to reset my password but without result.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems username-password usage is deprecated and you have to create a Personal Access Token.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token

Using this access token worked for me with the basic credential prompt, not when using the dialog window.